# Enforce dedicated graphics on MBP 2010

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics, gpu

My MBP (mid 2010) is suffering from the [Intermittent black screen or loss of video](http://support.apple.com/en-en/HT203554) issue. More specifically, it may happen that when switching from dedicated to integrated graphics, the screen goes black. Only a reboot helps in this case.

So I tried to disable the automatic graphics switching (via "System Preferences" -> "Energy Saver"). Nevertheless, graphics switching still occurs; I can't say when or what's causing that, though. It always appears to be the case after waking up from sleep / suspend-to-ram. As per gfxCardStatus, "Dynamic Switching" is enabled then, which is exactly what I seeked to prevent via the systems preferences.

Is there a way to permanently disable the dynamic graphics switching and only work with the discrete graphics? I wouldn't mind the shortened battery lifetime if that helped to prevent the black screen issue to occur.

Comment: gfxCardStatus should be able to do that, check the [official page on switching](https://gfx.io/switching.html) **edit:** oh, you mean that on wakeup gfxCardStatus automatically sets itself to dynamic?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's gfxCardStatus itself which sets it back to dynamic switching or something else. But using gfxCardStatus I can see that dynamic switching is enabled after wake-up. I'm looking for a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I don't have a compatible computer to do tests right now, but I think gfxCardStatus supports command-line commands. Can you try and see if executing this in the terminal changes modes?

`<route to app>/gfxCardStatus.app/Contents/MacOS/gfxCardStatus --discrete`

Other available commands are --dynamic and --integrated. If that works, a workaround solution would be to automatically launch that command on wakeup.

Comment: That's a good idea. Can you post it as answer? Then I'll award the bounty to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and see if executing this in the terminal changes modes?

`<route to app>/gfxCardStatus.app/Contents/MacOS/gfxCardStatus --discrete`

Other available commands are `--dynamic` and `--integrated`. If that works, a workaround solution would be to automatically launch that command on wakeup.

Answer (score 0):

now i don't know when you purchased your computer, but apple offers 3 years extended warranty for your computer, if you can, make an appointment to a local appplestore, and try to get your graphic card replaced for free!

Comment: It's mentioned in the link provided by the OP.

Comment: Unfortunately it's older than three years, so I'm not eligible for the free replacement.

Comment: have you tried it tho? apple is known for goodwill